# How to get the wildcard in the URL and apply argument to a link

Tags: javascript

Hello I am super new to building websites. Please excuse my lacking terminology!!

I have a website that has Wildcard sub-domains. It is using this script to pull the wildcard sub-domains usernames.

```
<p id="dist-info"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
return;

     var get_data_url = 'https://backoffice.WEBSITE.com/api/v2/public/users/{username}';

     $.getJSON(get_data_url, function( data ) {

          var dist_info = "<p>"+data.response['first-name']+"</p>" +

                        "<p>"+data.response['last-name']+"</p>" +

                        "<p>"+data.response['distributor-id']+" "+data.response.email+"</p>" +

                        "<p>"+data.response['image-url']+"</p>" +

                        "<p>Phone: "+data.response.phone+"</p>";

          $('#dist-info').html(dist_info);

     });

  });

</script>
```

Now I need to make a URL that will parse the username/user id out of the Wildcard Subdomain page. What code do I need to use?

For example

The URL is

USERNAME.WEBSITE.com/page/subpage/

I need to make this URL

backoffice.WEBSITE.com/page?sponsor-id=USERNAME

What do I need to do so that the username from the first page is parsed out and applied to the link of the second URL

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify this JavaScript so it uses the subdomain instead of {username}?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var get_data_url = 'https://backoffice.WEBSITE.com/api/v2/public/users/';

    var hostname_parts = location.hostname.split('.');
    var username = hostname_parts.shift();
    // add username to the data URL
    get_data_url += username;

    // add username to some link on the website
    var $aTag = $('#id-of-the-link');
    var link_url = $aTag.attr('href');
    link_url += username;
    // set the new href attribute
    $aTag.attr('href', link_url);
```

`location.hostname` gives you USERNAME.WEBSITE.com, `split()` splits it into parts separated by a dot. `shift()` takes the 1st element of this array (you could also use `hostname_parts[0]`) and with `+=` you concatenate it to the URL.

The second example shows how to add the username at the end of a link like

```
<a href="backoffice.WEBSITE.com/page?sponsor-id=" id="id-of-the-link">click</a>
```

Edit: added example for changing a href attribute

Comment: Let me clarify

The current script is good because it is helping me complete this:
USERNAME.WEBSITE.com/page/subpage/

What I like to know is if I need to modify the script to make this also happen:
backoffice.WEBSITE.com/page?sponsor-id=USERNAME

Essentially both URLs needs to be working. Do i need to modify the script as instructed? or is there something that I can add to the end of the URL to get that username.

Comment: scenario:
I am currently on this page:
USERNAME.WEBSITE.com/page/subpage/

and within this page, I have a link. This link needs to take the USERNAME from the current URL, and be inserted automatically into the link as such: 

backoffice.WEBSITE.com/page?sponsor-id=USERNAME

Comment: @Xiao I added an example of how you can use it to change the href attribute of a link.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response!  I am still running into issues with this. With the script and example, it is now combining the 1st URL + 2nd URL together. It isn't splitting up any parts. Another question is, can this code be possible as a direct URL without the additional [id="id-of-the-link"] added to the direct URL? I am using a plugin for this link and it is asking for direct URL

Comment: That shouldn't happen - the code above does not concatenate the URLs, it extracts the USERNAME from the hostname. Have you implemented it correctly? Also, I don't really get what you mean by "direct URL". What do you want to achieve? Which plugin are you using? Can you either post your code or an errors that you receive.

Comment: You are right, I put it in wrong the first time. I just tried it again AND ITS WORKING!!! THANK YOU!!!!!